# Urllib3 - Selenium ConnectionResetError - WinError 10054 - Initializing webdriver.Chrome

Tags: selenium

New post since previous one was marked as duplicate which is not the case I'm sorry.

I'm having some difficulties with urllib3 and Seleninum.

For some reason, one of my selenium scripts(the others are fine) is crashing at the very beginning while opening webdriver.Chrome.

*The error appears to be somehow "random". 
It won't work for a couple of hours, then works fine.*

What I'm not understanding is how the connection can be closed by the **remote host** if at this stage I am only initializing the browser?

Based on the log, this is where it fails :

```
chrome_webdriver = 'G:/Selenium/chromedriver_win32/chromedriver.exe'
chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument("--allow-insecure-localhost")
chrome_options.add_argument("--ignore-certificate-errors")
chrome_options.add_argument("log-level=3")
chrome_options.add_argument("--start-maximized")
try:
   logging.info("Starting webdriver")   
   browser = webdriver.Chrome(
        options=chrome_options,
        executable_path=chrome_webdriver)
   logging.info("Webdriver launched")   
except Exception as e:
   logging.error(repr(e))
   exit
```

I ran `netstat -b` on the host but I don't see the port being used nor in TIME_WAIT state while I just got :

```
INFO -- Starting webdriver
ERROR -- ProtocolError('Connection aborted.', ConnectionResetError(10054, 'An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host', None, 10054, None))
```

The complete error if it can help :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:\Python3\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 672, in urlopen
    chunked=chunked,
  File "E:\Python3\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 421, in _make_request
    six.raise_from(e, None)
  File "<string>", line 3, in raise_from
  File "E:\Python3\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 416, in _make_request
    httplib_response = conn.getresponse()
  File "E:\Python3\lib\http\client.py", line 1336, in getresponse
    response.begin()
  File "E:\Python3\lib\http\client.py", line 306, in begin
    version, status, reason = self._read_status()
  File "E:\Python3\lib\http\client.py", line 267, in _read_status
    line = str(self.fp.readline(_MAXLINE + 1), "iso-8859-1")
  File "E:\Python3\lib\socket.py", line 589, in readinto
    return self._sock.recv_into(b)
ConnectionResetError: [WinError 10054] An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
```

Any help would be appreciated, I am running out of ideas.

*Information*:

ChromeDriver 79.0.3945.36 (latest)

Chrome version is Version 79.0.3945.130 (latest)

Firewall is disabled

Urllib3 version : 1.25.8

Python version : 3.7.4

Comment: Were things stable until Chrome got updated? I wonder if downgrading Chrome and ChromeDriver will fix this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know why, but switching the selenium from Chrome to Firefox did the work and the script is working as expected.

I still don't understand why I have this bug - Winerror 100054 - only with Chrome but at least it's working if anyone come across this post